# How to write in the SDRAM - STM32

Tags: stm32f7

I have a board including stm32f767 .The LTDC unit is set and the LCD works well.I want to define an array in the SDRAM. I defined it in the Address: 0XCF000000 that does not have overlap with the LCD frame buffer:
u16 Buffertest[200] **attribute**((at(0XCF000000)))

But when I run the program, the LCD was hanged.

I would be grateful to hear your guidance.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use the external SDRAM, your data has to be 4byte aligned. So you cannot use a 16 bit array. All your values have to be 32 bit. So change your array type to an u32.